# javascript src file 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am facing error "file not found" in an angular javascript. I am using Nodejs and express for server and angularjs in html5. AngularChart.html is in "public" folder in which I am trying to refer one javascript in one level up.

> script type="text/javascript" src="../check.js"

It is giving me the error in console.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/check.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my folder structure.

```
\myapp\public\AngularChart.html
\myapp\check.js
```

it works when in refer files folder down but nothing working in folder up. I suspect it may be because of the __dirname in app.js which is as below.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` you're only exposing `public`, so, make sure you have all the public files in this directory...

Answer (score 1):

Your **chart.js** should be **public** so add it inside the **public** directory otherwise it gives a **404** error (**Not** **found**) since it is not visible to the client.(browser)

Comment: Accepted. But what i need to change if i have to refer some js file from node_module , which is one level up directory ?

Comment: if you are planning to use **node_module** by using **npm install** it is recommended to use webpack like module builders for **view** or use **cdn**  for those libraries